# How can I fix missing bullet point characters in Word Online?

Tags: fonts, office365

I'm using Word Online in Ubuntu and the bullet points don't appear correctly. This is what it looks like in Firefox:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Update

I submitted [a bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1533797) and this issue has been fixed as of Firefox 68.

This issue originally affected all browsers, but Microsoft fixed it for Chrome by adding downloadable versions of the fonts to the Word Online site.

The workaround is below in case this is still broken for other browsers.

### Workaround

1. Install the missing fonts locally

   ```
   mkdir -p ~/.fonts/
   wget https://source.winehq.org/git/wine.git/blob/HEAD:/fonts/symbol.ttf -O ~/.fonts/symbol.ttf
   wget https://source.winehq.org/git/wine.git/blob/HEAD:/fonts/wingding.ttf -O ~/.fonts/wingding.ttf
   wget https://bmaupin.github.io/askubuntu-983191-research/symbol_msfontservice.ttf -O ~/.fonts/symbol_msfontservice.ttf
   wget https://bmaupin.github.io/askubuntu-983191-research/wingdings_msfontservice.ttf -O ~/.fonts/wingdings_msfontservice.ttf
   fc-cache -f -v
   ```
2. Once that's done, the bullet points should be fixed:

   [image]

### Details

Examining the source of the page, here's the information on the various bullet points:

- First level

  - Character: unicode f0b7 ()
  - Font: Symbol
- Second level

  - Character: o
  - Font: Courier New
- Third level

  - Character: unicode f0a7 ()
  - Font: Wingdings

You can find more details than you ever wanted to know about this issue here: https://github.com/bmaupin/askubuntu-983191-research#readme

Comment: Thanks. This made it work for me in Chrome, but not Firefox. Any idea about making it work for the latter?

Comment: This has improved the amount of bullet characters available to me, but the default solid black bullet (symbol f0b7) is still unavailable for me. Ubuntu 18.04, Firefox.

Comment: I spent some time digging into the issue and I've come up with a viable workaround for Firefox. I've updated my answer to reflect that. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: This problem happened in Firefox 83.0, and your solution fixed it

Answer (score 3):

I have the same issue, tried [your solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/983192/22949), but the problem remained. It was as though the wingdings is not well installed.

Word Online:
[In Word Online, selecting: bullets / Define new bullet / Wingdings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARboV.png)

LibreOffice:
[In LibreOffice, inserting special character](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eL78i.png)

**What succeeded at fixing it** was to download the font from https://github.com/IamDH4/ttf-wps-fonts/blob/master/wingding.ttf.  I placed it directly in `/usr/share/fonts/truetype/`. Then I ran:

```
sudo fc-cache -rv
```

Comment: I just managed to fix it ! I downloaded the font from : "https://github.com/IamDH4/ttf-wps-fonts/blob/master/wingding.ttf", I placed it directly in "/usr/share/fonts/truetype/", then I ran : "sudo fc-cache -rv"

Comment: I found Symbol and Wingdings in other places online but I'm not sure about their licensing. The fonts from Wine work and have an open license. Did you close/repoen your browser afterward? that part's important. Also, your system should pick up fonts in ~/.fonts without having to edit system-wide fonts. What browser are you using? The answer I posted worked in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Tried getting the fonts from this github repository and from the Wine package as detailed in the previous answer. Both do fix many of the missing characters in Word Online. However neither of them fix the issue with the default bullet character for me.

Answer (score 1):

I already had wine installed, so this worked for me:

```
cd ~/.fonts
ln -s /usr/share/wine/fonts wine
fc-cache
```

I didn't even have to restart Firefox.